# Can I flash a separate radio image and have a working radio?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, twrp, cellular-radio

I have a rooted LGE Nexus 4. Installed on it are [the Team Win Recovery Project](http://teamw.in) and CyanogenMod 13 (Android 6).

I found [this guide](http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=06.%20Thoughts&proj=02.%20Android%20M%20on%20Nexus4) to installing stock Android 6 onto a Nexus 4, and it provides pre-built system and boot images, alongside:

> ... an OLD radio (initial radio release for Mako), [and then] this ROM will support LTE :)

In the comments section of that post, a user added how to install the pre-built image:

> 3. From command terminal:
>
>    ```
>    fastboot flash boot boot.img
>    fastboot flash system system.img
>    fastboot flash radio lte_modem.img (or normal_modem.img)
>    fastboot reboot-bootloader
>    ```

My question boils down to, can I just flash the `lte_modem.img` alone and come out with a working phone with CM13?

If that isn't inherently answerable, then: if something goes wrong, can I flash `normal_modem.img`, or do I need a CM13-specific radio image? Where do I get that special `radio.img`?

Comment: You don't need a special radio image for Cm13

Comment: Radio.img or Boot.img

Comment: @user157947 what?

Comment: Your looking for the Hybrid Radio Images, which are a combination of the "old" mobile data modem and the "new" WiFi modem merged together, there are several sources for this on XDA, start by looking in the Nexus 4 General area. This will enable LTE which was disabled by Google shortly after release. The hardware of the N4 only supports Band 4 LTE, which is only used by T-Mobile network wide, AT&T in limited areas, and most Canadian carriers, it is not used anywhere else in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Previous) Nexus 4 owner reporting in.

People at XDA had long been using hybrid modems with custom ROMs like CM. It seems specific versions are needed for each major Android version (JB/KK/LP+), but there's a nifty app right here you can try out: [LINK: Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.bpear.makomodem&hl=en).

Also, there's no special radio for CM13. No custom ROM team makes radio themselves. Just flash back to a stock radio if things go wrong.

Comment: Also remember this only enables Band 4 LTE, which is used in North America only... If your carrier does not use Band 4, the hybrid radios will do nothing but increase battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

It sound's fishy ... or its a Brand specific image partition.
I have only ever seen the radio information built into the boot.img ... Unless it's an MTK aka MediaTek device, Then it requires flashing with SP Flashtool aka Smart Phone Flash Tool ...

The SP Flashtool version usually wipes the radio with a complete firmware upgrade, This is why most tutorials specifically state to use DOWNLOAD MODE .. In Firmware upgrade mode it will completely delete all partitions, and reinstalls the selected images...

Usually firmware upgrade will destroy NV-RAM " radio files " and then you will need to use IMEI Serial writer or SN Write Station to re-flash the NVram back with stock IMEI and Serial numbers (Bluetooth adress, Wifi mac etc...)     Under the battery or on original box

If you can ring `*#06#` and it says IMEI = null, Then you need a radio, otherwise the radio is fine... Usually your IMEI gets stored in the same place as radio for security i imagine.

If you open INFO by calling `*#*#4636#*#*` aka `*#*#INFO#*#*`You should see Phone info as a section, 
- Open Phone info
- Press menu for more options or scroll down
- Press the WCDMA + GSM or whatever yours is, And try to select LTE ... If nothing happens then it's usually a hardware issue or limitation .. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN3pm.jpg)

Comment: When I ring `*#06#`, it gives me my IMEI, not `null`. When I dial `##INFO##` it says `USSD code running` and then nothing happens.